# Rails 2.3: Session not available for first request after server restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I'm currently upgrading a rails application from 2.1.0 to 2.3.14.
Most things are running well now, but there's a strange issue with the user sessions:

When a user has been logged in, this is saved in the session and is available even after a browser restart - as it should.

However: When I restart my local server and load a page that requires authentication, the following happens:

1. Rails creates a new session row in the database with exactly the same session_id as before.
2. Inside the application the "old" session is not available, old session data is not available.
3. If I simply reload the page (F5) afterwards, the correct session including the old data is loaded fine.

The application uses `ActionController::Base.session_store = :active_record_store` and multiple databases (one per subdomain, wasn't my decision). The correct database is chosen as before_filter and rails saves sessions in these databases.

My guess is that after a server restart something is not yet set correctly and the sessions are searched in a wrong database and kept for the first request (but it's saved in the correct database after it was set via `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection`).

If my guess is correct, loading the correct session after establishing the connection should solve this. 
Is there a way to either completely reload the session from database or tell Rails to use a custom database for all sessions?

Thanks in advance!